# How to highlight cells in Excel that end in a numeric value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I work at a library and I'm given a report to create an Outdated Stock Report/Shelf Lists that rely on an item's Publication Date. Unfortunately, because of the nature of serial publications, the publication date is the original publication date of the serial and the date of that specific copy is put at the end of the call number. This is a Cataloging thing and cannot be changed. Example:
[image: Title of books, followed by Publication Date (first example is 1984), then the Call Number (Call Number ends in 2014)]

I have VBA coding that takes the database report run by IT, filters by the Publication Date, and then takes Call Numbers beginning with a certain Dewey number and puts them on their own sheet. In the image example above, these were items that had a Dewey number between 910 and 919 (Geography, Atlases, & Travel) and a Publication Date of older than 5 years. Because of the serial publication example I just gave, some newer publications are ending up on this report as older/outdated. All of the items in the image above are newer than their Publication Date "suggests." This is only really a problem with serial publications and most of the items in the library are NOT serials.

Unfortunately, this creates some confusion if a librarian is not paying attention. I thought that maybe I could highlight Call Number cells that contain a year (or numeric value) at the end because almost always only serial call numbers have numbers at the end and this would alert the librarian to look at the year at the end of the call number instead of the Publication Date in that case. Many of the items in the example are still "outdated" but as you can see from the highlighted two, those are new and should not be considered for weeding. I have racked my brain on a different way of doing the coding, but all seem more time consuming and convoluted for just a small segment of our items.

So, I did the Google searches and found various things about conditional formatting if there is a **specific** value at the end, but none that say if there is ANY numeric value at the end.

To reiterate: I want coding that looks at the Call Number cells, evaluates the last four characters of the string, and if they are numeric, applies conditional formatting (highlighting) to that cell. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Your example is confusing.  I believe “Fodor’s New Orleans” (“917.6335 TAY 2018”) should also be highlighted, because it’s less than five years old (and the Dewey number is between 910 and 919).  (2) You ask about highlighting for manual attention, but I wonder why you don't want your VBA code to handle this.  (3) On the other hand, there is a book called [*2666*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6372225-2666).  What if somebody writes a sequel to *1984* or *Fahrenheit 451* that ends with a number greater than 2017?

Comment: @Scott (1) I just highlighted those 2021s as an example of two that definitely don't need to be on there, not as the only ones that should be highlighted, because in my question, all those would be highlighted for attention to tell the librarians to look at them closer. See, this is already filtered, once by my VBA coding, and then another time by me for the example picture. These are just a few of many entries on this report, and of course "Fodor's New Orleans" is a Dewey number between 910 & 919 b/c it is on the report in the first place.

Comment: @Scott (2) I would have my VBA coding do this. I just need to know the coding to put into my VBA coding... thought that was clear. (3) Your examples would not have the year at the end. First, that's not how Dewey works, just because the title has a date in it doesn't mean it has that date in the Dewey. 2nd Fiction is not considered for Outdated Stock. 3rd, these are all examples of monographs and not serial publications.

Answer (score 1):

This formula can work as a conditional format formula.

```
    =NUMBERVALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(A2,4)))>1000
```

Reading inside out, it's taking the last 4 characters of the cell, then trimming spaces, then converting that to a number, and finally checking to see if that value is greater than 1000. If so, value is TRUE. Change the 1000 to a value that makes sense to you (ie, safely older than the oldest 4-digit year you would expect).

[image]